# Still resource leak after closing BufferedReader

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I'm still learning Java and I need some help understanding why this code is wrong:

```
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String regel = infile.readLine();
while (regel != null) {
    // Do something with regel.
    regel = infile.readLine();
}
infile.close();
```

I really don't see the problem but Eclipse keeps telling there is a resource leak and that infile isn't closed.

(one more detail, this code stands in a try block but I left it away to keep it simple)

Comment: Think about what happens if `readLine` throws an exception.

Comment: Java 7 supports [*AutoCloseable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

Comment: Tried your code on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php with try catch. It works without any complain.

Comment: @Wajahat: It is a *complaint* from IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse is complaining because the reference may not be closed (for example, in an Exception); this is where you would use a `finally` block - perhaps like so

```
BufferedReader infile = null;
try {
  infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String regel = infile.readLine();
  while (regel != null) {
    // Do something with regel.
    regel = infile.readLine();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); // Log the exception.
} finally {
  if (infile != null) {
    infile.close(); // close the resource.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a try/catch block.

Also you should use the following instead:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 //do something with line;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Elliott Frisch is correct and pointed out the main reason the only thing I would add is You should close the stream (in a finally block) because to ensure that any output buffers are flushed in the case that output was otherwise successful. If the flush fails, the code should exit via an exception. Here is another example similar to what you are trying to solve and make sure you look at (**Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases**) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html

```
    final OutputStream rawOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        final BufferedOutputStream out =
            new BufferedOutputStream(rawOut);
        use(out);
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        rawOut.close();
    }
```